# Why Is My Distance Travelled Overshooting?

Tags: integration

I have the following pascal code to determine position and velocity from acceleration:

```
For x:= 1 to 10
Do Begin

    Velocity:=Velocity + Acceleration;
    Position := Position + Velocity;
    Writeln(Position);
    End;
```

Why am I overshooting?

Answer (score 1):

You are overshooting because your code assumes that the updated velocity was valid  for the entire duration of this tick of the clock.

You get better accuracy if you use (inside the loop)

```
Begin
  NewVelocity:=Velocity+Acceleration;
  Position:=Position+(Velocity+NewVelocity)/2;
  writeln(Position);
  Velocity:=NewVelocity;
End;
```

This will be accurate, iff the acceleration is uniform, because it uses the average of the old and updated velocities. If the acceleration is not uniform (say, celestial bodies moving under gravity) then this is still just an approximation.

Comment: It is more accurate to say that with your original snippet you are overshooting when the acceleration is positive, and undershooting when it is negative. The reason is the same. The difference is that with a positive acceleration you use too large a value for the average velocity (during a tick), whereas with a negative acceleration you use too small a value.

Comment: I'm so confused. As we are using fixed timesteps, surely we can be 100% sure that Velocity = Velocity + Acceleration and that Position = Velocity.

Comment: Oh I think it may have just clicked! Are we saying that it's inaccurate because between x and (x+1) the velocity is changing and therefore our position is increasing at an exponential rate?

Comment: Not "exponential", but definitely not linear either. (In point of fact, it's quadratic.)

Comment: @Martin: That's exactly the reason! You can also test it for example as follows. Make your clock tick faster. Say, you would run the loop a hunderd times instead of ten so that each iteration takes only 0.1 seconds. You would then of course update like `position=position+0.1*velocity`and `velocity=velocity+0.1*acceleration`. You would still overshoot, but considerably less.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations, you've just entered the wide world of numerical integration.  You're trying to take a system of ordinary differential equations like this:

$$x'(t) = v(t), \quad v'(t) = a(t)$$

And use numerical data at a fixed interval of $h = 1$ to estimate the true values of $x$ and $v$ at $t=10$.

You can estimate the error inherent in such a scheme from a Taylor series expansion.  Let's look at just $v$:

$$v(t+h) \approx v(t) + a(t) h + \frac{1}{2} v''(t) h^2 + \ldots $$

In particular, notice that because you chose $h=1$, the $h^2$ term could be as large as the order $h$ term if $v'' \geq 2a$.  That naturally jeopardizes the validity of your scheme, as it represents something potentially large that you didn't account for.  One way to attack this problem is to simply use a smaller step $h$.  As you choose a smaller $h$, the quadratic term will be reduced.

---

Of course, you may not always be able to use better resolution, and even if you can, it is only part of an overall strategy to a better numerical integration.

In the above, I used a simple Taylor series expansion corresponding to the kind of scheme used in the question.  It basically comes down to the idea that we can estimate $v(t+h)$ from $a(t)$ to a certain error.  But what if we used more values of $a$ in the interval $[t, t+h]$ and could reduce the error?  Basically, we use more Taylor expansions to try to eliminate error terms.  For instance, consider

$$\begin{align*}
v(t+h) &= v(t+h/2) + a(t+h/2) \frac{h}{2} + \frac{1}{2} v''(t+h/2) \frac{h^2}{4} + O(h^3)\\
v(t) &= v(t+h/2) - a(t+h/2) \frac{h}{2} + \frac{1}{2} v''(t+h/2) \frac{h^2}{4} + O(h^3)\end{align*}$$

You can use these to derive a scheme that is third-order accurate in the stepsize $h$:

$$v(t+h) = v(t) + a (t+h/2) h + O(h^3)$$

Basically, we use the acceleration at the midpoint of the step, rather than the beginning of the step.  But, this may be impractical if all you have is acceleration data on the actual step values.

---

At any rate, the method you're using--called an "Euler step"--is very simple, and also not very accurate.  It is hardly surprising to see it over or undershoot significantly.  Consider a smaller step if possible to decrease error, but also consider a more sophisticated method.  I just drew one up above, but even that is very simple. Runge-Kutta methods (look them up) are quite common.

Whatever you use, understand that from a numerical standpoint, you are using an *approximation* to try to recover $x$ and $v$ at the future times.  Approximations have intrinsic error.  A more sophisticated scheme, or decreasing the step size, can reduce error.  The Euler scheme that you're using is not exact for a *general* acceleration.

Comment: Is there any way we can obtain an exact position with a constant acceleration?

Comment: You would want $x(t+1) = x(t) + v(t) + a/2$ and $v(t+1) = v(t) + a$. You can substitute $a = v(t+1)-v(t)$ into the $x$ equation and get the scheme from @JyrkiLahtonen as a result. - Take note while $v(t+1) = v(t) + a$ for constant $a$, it is not true that $x(t+1) = x(t) + v(t)$ because the velocity is *not* constant over the interval.

Comment: @Murphid, Interesting! I've encountered that formula before. It seems to be the standard way of calculating position versus time in most motion controllers. However, when I try to implement it, I still end up overshooting.   Could you provide an example of its use and implementation? I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Don't know if there's anything else I can do from here; the scheme is sound as far as I know, so any further issues with computing the correct position/velocity are out of the scope of this answer--e.g. having to do with implementation, perhaps. - Maybe you could describe the exact situation that you're trying to model and give numerical data for what you have versus what the scheme predicts?

Comment: @Murphid, this is the code I have:
For Time := 1 to 10
Do Begin
  Velocity := Velocity + Acceleration;
  Position := Position + Velocity + Acceleration/2;

It seems obvious that it would overshoot because it's essentially my original implementation with an added value.
I've seen the method implemented in this way before.

Comment: Because you updated the velocity first and then used the *new* value to update the position, which is not what the scheme I wrote does.

Comment: @Murphid, right so I should just switch the two assignments around? I've seen other systems calculate velocity first with this method and then calculate position. VK = VK-1 + A;
        PK = PK-1 + VK-1 +A/2.
An Example:
void t(void)
{
 
 OLDPBUF=MOVPBUF;     // save the last position
    MOVVBUF = MOVVBUF+A;    // new velocity
    
     MOVPBUF = MOVVBUF+A_2+ MOVPBUF; // new position
   dvdt=MOVPBUF-OLDPBUF;
}

Comment: I don't see how that scheme would work; it still uses the new velocity to update the position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25745/discussion-between-martin-rand-and-muphrid).